# Use jenkins workspace as webroot using nginx

Tags: nginx, jenkins

I' configured by jenkins to re-build my dev-branch after every commit - now I'd like to host the result.

I'm very new to Ubuntu and nginx / jenkins. My setup is like this

Jenkins workspace is in

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/**my-project**
```

Virtual host config:

```
server {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/my-project.log;

    listen  443 ssl http2;
    server_name my-project.my-domain.de;

    ssl_certificate      my-project-fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  my-project-privkey.pem;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/my-project/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

I've created a symlink from /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/**my-project** to /usr/share/nginx/html/

Currently I simply get a 404 not found when trying to access my subdomain

When being in the workspace folder i have the following output for ls -la

[image: ls -la]

I somehow know i might need to change privileges or the chown, but I don't want to screw up the security by doing something wrong.

Comment: Hi Frank. I noticed this question has yet to find an answer - did you ever come up with a solution? If not, you might consider migrating this to Server Fault to see if you can get an answer there.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I actually found an answer and will add it

Answer (score 0):

For my current solution I've added the jenkins user to the www/data user group and changed the owner of the workspace folders to

**jenkins::www/data**

By this I was able to use it as web root for my nginx.